# How to delete unused JS code from popular libraries?

Tags: recaptcha, google-pagespeed, lighthouse

I've connected google reCaptcha and crisp to my project. When I check website speed [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), it shows a performance issue that says "Remove unused JavaScript" for these files:

- [recaptcha_en.js](https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/IU7gZ7o6RDdDE6U4Y1YJJWnN/recaptcha__en.js)
- [client.js](https://client.crisp.chat/static/javascripts/client.js?98cb4fa)

How can I solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

recaptcha_en.js: It might actually be used. Google page speed is just complaining that it isn't used right away. You should modify the loading of recaptcha to load when the relevent form is selected (focused). This will fix the "Remove unused JavaScript" problem. It will also keep your users from getting timeout errors if you are using recaptcha v3.

For client.js you could solve by defering and loading asychronously. Not sure if that file is neccecary right away for your specific site.